# Q How to Plot n-gram positions in text

Tags: python, plot, n-gram

I'm trying to plot position and frequency of the n-gram recurrence in text.  The idea is to identify points in text, where the author starts reusing the terms. Some genres should have a shorter uniqueness span than others.

Word 1...n, placed on the X axis. As the frequency of n-gram recurrence becomes > 1, a dot appears on the plot, where X is its position, Y is the frequency and colour is the unique n-gram. From the code below 2-gram "good sport" would be plotted as (7, 2, RED).

Q: How can I create the np.array with 1.unique n-gram,2.  frequency and 3. position in text?

```
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
    import nltk

    words = "good day, good night, good sport, good sport charlie"
    clean=re.sub("[^\w\d'\s]+",'',words)

    vectorizer2 = CountVectorizer( ngram_range=(2,2),         tokenizer=word_tokenize, stop_words='english')
    analyzer = vectorizer2.build_analyzer()
    two_grams=analyzer(clean)


    # Get the set of unique words.
    uniques = []
    for word in two_grams:
        if word not in uniques:
            uniques.append(word)

    # Make a list of (count, unique) tuples.
    counts = []
    for unique in uniques:
        count = 0              # Initialize the count to zero.
        for word in two_grams:     # Iterate over the words.
            if word == unique:   # Is this word equal to the current unique?
                count += 1         # If so, increment the count
        counts.append((count, unique))


    counts.sort()            # Sorting the list puts the lowest counts first.
    counts.reverse()         # Reverse it, putting the highest counts first.
    # Print the ten words with the highest counts.
    for i in range(min(10, len(counts))):
        count, word = counts[i]
        print('%s %d' % (word, count))

    #Scatterplot

    #plt.scatter(count, count, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
   ####plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think before you try scikit learn, it's better to start with a simple and thoughtful algorithm.

In the case if your engram, it's possible to iterate over the characters of the string until the 1st character matches, and then

```
ngram = "good sport"
words = "good day, good night, good sport, good sport charlie"

loc = []
k = 0
while k < len(words):
    if words[k] != ngram[0]:
        k += 1
    elif words[k: k+ len(ngram)] == ngram:
        loc += [k]
        k += 1
    else:
        k += 1
```

This returns `loc = [22,34]`.  Any list can be turn into an array, such as `L = np.array(loc)`.

No claim this is efficient or fail-proof, but it's better to understand what it is your are coding into scikit-learn